# Adding Griffith's script r to Lyx

Tags: lyx

I've gotten Griffiths' script r from his website https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/griffiths/ and have things working in just a regular Latex editor. I compile using PDFLatex. I would like to get things working in Lyx but I'm having a hard time finding out how to get it all set up. Has anyone done this and knows how best to get it working in Lyx?

Comment: Welcome into the community of TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way, for a single document at least, would be to place `ScriptR.pdf` and `BoldR.pdf` in the same folder as the `.lyx` file, and then go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble in the LyX document, and add

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\rcurs{{\mbox{$\resizebox{.16in}{.08in}{\includegraphics{ScriptR}}$}}}
\def\brcurs{{\mbox{$\resizebox{.16in}{.08in}{\includegraphics{BoldR}}$}}}
\def\hrcurs{{\mbox{$\hat \brcurs$}}}
```

from the sample `.tex` file. (If you have already added an image to the document via the LyX GUI, you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}`.)

To use them, add an ERT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and type e.g. `\rcurs`. If in math mode, then I don't think you need to type the backslash, i.e. type just `rcurs` after hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: That worked great! I wasn't putting the images in the same directory so I was getting errors, but now it's working. As a follow up, do you know how to make it show up in Lyx as a preview or do I just need keep the command in written form?